# Delicious bookmarks count not retrieving

Tags: php, jquery, delicious-api

I am using the below code to get the delicious bookmarks count of some sites. But it's not working fine.
Is there any problem with the API or my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#delicious').click(function() {
        $("#delicious_result").text("Loading......");
        var url = $('#url').val();
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://feeds.delicious.com/v2/json/urlinfo/data?url="+url+"&amp;callback=?",
            success: function(data) {
                var count = 0;
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    count = data[0].total_posts;
                }
                $("#delicious_result").text(count + ' Saved');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have contacted the delicious.com support. The issue is with their api for several days and did not noted until reported. Now its working.